# highcharts missing markers occasionally

Tags: jquery, highcharts

The markers in the chart work normally sometimes but randomly disappears sometimes. The options are

```
plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
          fillOpacity: 1
        },
        series: {
          tooltip: {
           dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second:"%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S"
          }
        },
        marker: {
          fillColor: '#3D84B1',
          lineWidth: 2,
          lineColor: 'white',
          radius: 6

        }
      }
    },
```

Here is how it looks with points

[image]

and here is how it looks with missing points

[image]

Any ideas on whats happening or how to fix it

Comment: Are you using two series stacked ? post complete code or a fiddle with problem illustration.

Comment: No the series aren't stacked, I can't post a fiddle because the problem only happens sometimes which made it hard to debug and fix

Comment: Is the issue visible when there is relatively large amount of points in relation to chart's size (width)? If yes, then this will be a setting that hides markers if there is not enough space for a chart that is not overflown with makers. [Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there I was ignoring the seconds from timestamp while parsing the date time for graph, fixed it.